# event preventDefault error

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can I add event preventDefault on this functions , I try added it on the top , but on this function wont load event preventDefault how can I add on them? I also try to use annnymous functions on them to add event preventDefault , but it doesnt work ....  the problem is about how to delete the url from request post or get , because once I click any a then is trigged by a hash # I wanted to try to delete the hash with defaultPrevent , but it didnt work.

```
$('#search').typeahead({
        source: function (query, process) {
            $.ajax({
                url: URL_SEARCH_PRODUCT,
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    query: query
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                async: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    process(data);
                    data.forEach(function (item) {
                        var options = $("ul.typeahead li");
                        options.each(function (indice, option) {
                            if ($(option).find("a").text() === item.name) {
                                $(option).find("a").attr("data-id", item.id);
                                $(option).find("a").attr("data-name", item.name);
                                $(option).find("a").attr("data-qty", item.qty);
                                $(option).find("a").attr("data-price", item.price);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        },
        afterSelect: function (item) {
            $("#search").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            var actual = $("ul.typeahead li.active a");
            var actual_id = $(actual).data("id");
            var actual_name = $(actual).data("name");
            var actual_qty = 1;
            var actual_price = $(actual).data("price");
            add_cart(actual_id, actual_name, actual_qty, actual_price, 1);
            $("#search").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
```

checkout

```
$("#checkout").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#checkout_pay").validate();
        BootstrapDialog.show({
            title: '',
            message: function (dialog) {
                var $message = $('<div></div>');
                var pageToLoad = dialog.getData('pageToLoad');
                $message.load(pageToLoad);
                return $message;
            },
            data: {
                pageToLoad: URL_GET_PAYMANET
            },
            cssClass: 'payment-dialog',
            buttons: [{
                label: 'Pay',
                cssClass: 'btn-primary',
                action: function (dialog) {
                    if ($("#checkout_pay").valid()) {
                        BootstrapDialog.confirm({
                            title: '',
                            message: 'Deseas completar la orden?',
                            type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_WARNING,
                            closable: false,
                            btnCancelLabel: 'no',
                            btnOKLabel: 'yes',
                            btnOKClass: 'btn-warning',
                            callback: function (result) {
                                if (result) {
                                    var total = $("#amount_tendered").val();
                                    var cantidad_pagada = $("#cantidad_pagada").val();
                                    if (Number(cantidad_pagada) >= Number(total)) {
                                        var datos_formulario = new FormData();
                                        datos_formulario.append("total", total);
                                        datos_formulario.append("cantidad_pagada", cantidad_pagada);
                                        $.ajax({
                                            url: URL_SELL_CART,
                                            method: 'POST',
                                            data: datos_formulario,
                                            processData: false,
                                            contentType: false,
                                            success: function (data) {
                                                if (data == 1) {
                                                    $.ajax({
                                                        url: URL_GET_CART,
                                                        method: 'POST',
                                                        dataType: 'json',
                                                        success: function (data) {
                                                            setCartHtml(data);
                                                        }
                                                    });
                                                    BootstrapDialog.show({
                                                        type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_SUCCESS,
                                                        message: 'Sale completed!, the change due is: ' + (Number(cantidad_pagada) - Number(total))
                                                    });
                                                } else {
                                                    BootstrapDialog.show({
                                                        type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_DANGER,
                                                        message: 'please enter the money before accept'
                                                    });
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                                    } else {
                                        BootstrapDialog.show({
                                            type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_DANGER,
                                            message: 'The payment must be equal or higher than the total'
                                        });
                                    }
                                    return false;
                                } else {}
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }]
        });
    });
```

Comment: Please explain problem in more detail. Take some time to read through [ask]

Comment: `typeahead` isn't an event, it's initializing a plugin. There's no default to prevent.

Comment: how can I add default to prevent ?? will it be impossible or will I always have it in url?